# Block diagonal matrix with offsets Python

Tags: numpy

Numpy provides a way to create a diagonal matrix from single elements using offset. Now, instead of single elements, I have a list of 2*2 blocks to insert along a diagonal with a specified offset. 
Below is 11 blocks of 2*2 arrays that should fit along the +1 offset of a 24*24 matrix. I am aware that scipy.linalg.block_diag can create a block diagonal for an (implicit) offset of zero.

In general, I have a list of 2*2 block arrays and I want to insert these blocks along specified offsets from the main 2*2 block diagonal

```
[array([[ 1,  8],[ 5, 40]]), array([[ 2,  7],[10, 35]]), array([[0, 0],        [0, 0]]), array([[ 3, 6],[15, 30]]), array([[ 4, 5],[20, 25]]),array([[0, 0],[0, 0]]), array([[ 5, 4],[25, 20]]), array([[ 6, 3],[30, 15]]), array([[0, 0],[0, 0]]), array([[ 7, 2],[35, 10]]), array([[ 8, 1], [40, 5]])]
```

Comment: All `block_diag` does is iterate through the blocks and insert into the right slice, `out[r:r + rr, c:c + cc] = arrs[i]`.  There's no magical compiled code here.  Just plain iteration and indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `block_diag` create an offset by prepending and appending an array of width/height zero:

```
from scipy import linalg

blocks = np.multiply.outer(np.arange(1,4), np.ones((2,2), int))
offset = 3
aux = np.empty((0, offset), int)

linalg.block_diag(aux.T, *blocks, aux)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]])
linalg.block_diag(aux, *blocks, aux.T)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the offset here inserts the blocks below the main diagonal. I would rather have positive offsets above the main diagonal and negative offsets below the main diagonal

Comment: @Sommy Please look again. Whether the blocks go below or above is simply a matter of swapping `aux` and `aux.T`.

Comment: This solution helped me, but I'm really struggling to understand why it works. If someone could explain it a little bit that would be great